# Result from Mono<Object> is null

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

I have the following code which I want to use to convert `Mono<Object>` to plain `Object`.

```
Mono<BasicTokenResponseDto> response = responseMono.map(obj -> {
            BasicTokenResponseDto tokenResponse = new BasicTokenResponseDto();
            tokenResponse.setApi_key(obj.getApi_key());
            return tokenResponse;
        });

.....

AtomicReference<BasicTokenResponseDto> plainJavaObject = new AtomicReference<>();
    Mono<BasicTokenResponseDto> tokenMono = clientService.getJwt();
    tokenMono.subscribe(transformedToken -> {
      plainJavaObject.set(transformedToken);
    });
    BasicTokenResponseDto token = plainJavaObject.get();

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + token.getApi_key());
```

Full code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/gateway_reactive_feign_poc/blob/master/gateway/src/main/java/com/gateway/filters/global/AuthenticationFilter.java#L39

But the value is null. Do you know how to properly return the object value?

Comment: You need to print within the subscribe, otherwise the print happens before the set is called

Comment: Can you show me code implementation please?

Comment: Move the System.out.println up 4 lines, within the subscribe body

Comment: The solution works. But I need to have access to `BasicTokenResponseDto`  object instance later. How I can access this object into Java method body like the original code?

Comment: You didn't share your original code so I'm not sure what you're referring to. Asynchronous code cannot be written the same as synchronous. Unwrapping a Mono/Flux get function creates synchronous code, and cannot be used "chronologically before" a setter

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/rcbandit111/gateway_reactive_feign_poc/blob/master/gateway/src/main/java/com/gateway/filters/global/AuthenticationFilter.java#L44

Comment: I need to find a way `BasicTokenResponseDto token` to be used later on into the code to get a value.

Comment: That link is the same code in the question, which doesn't work the way you want

Comment: Yes, is it possible to find some solution?

Comment: See chaining request example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-custom-gateway-filters#3-chaining-requests-to-other-services

Comment: hm.. Can you show me how to implement this into my code, please?

Comment: I don't know how to use the your clientService variable, so cannot help with that

Comment: Please include the all related source code, it's impossible to answer looking just on part of it

Comment: https://github.com/rcbandit111/gateway_reactive_feign_poc/tree/master/gateway/src/main/java/com/gateway

Comment: This is the repository with code example

Comment: @PeterPenzov that not how it works with SO actually, you need the code in the question. Otherwise how people will understand the question specifics years from now when you'll delete your external repo somehow? Also no one has a time to read the whole github repo, that's why people ask to include only a relevant part / a summary.

Comment: What are you going to do with obtained BasicTokenResponseDto? How should it be used for authentication?

Comment: later on I will do a custom verification. So I need the Object payload.